# Qt and app data storage in Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, storage

I am working on a mobile app, using Qt/C++, right now focusing on Android.
My app needs to store some permanent data, in a private and secure way (not accessible to other apps, protected as much as possible):

- some basic key/value settings: QSettings seems to be what I need here. The question being where does this end up in Android, is it stored in the shared preferences section?
- binary files, such as a few pics (these are created by the app, not static resources). I would have stored this in an internal storage file; where would I store this in Qt? Do I use Qt's file capabilities, and java calls to find my app's internal storage folder, or is there a Qt object designed for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android maintains a standard storage for applications under the path `/data/user/0` , where each application gets storage space. so if you have an application named `org.qtproject.example.myApp`, Android automatically creates storage space for this app:

```
/data/user/0/org.qtproject.example.myApp
```

The settings are stored under the `files` folder of this path, as `../files/.config/OrganizationName/AppName.conf`

When you want to store information in Android you don't use absolute paths, instead you specify the location of your storage using Qt `QStandardPaths` which usually returns location under the application path mentioned above, so for example to store a file `mySomeFile`, you would set the path using `QStandardPaths` like:

```
auto path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
auto fileName= path + "/mySomeFile";
```

and the file is stored as :

```
/data/user/0/org.qtproject.example.myApp/files/mySomeFile
```

Comment: Great, this really clarifies things and points me in the right direction.

Comment: @Will59, just note if you want to explore these paths an Android device, use a testing rooted device (didn't check emulator) for that `adb shell` is useful

Comment: A rooted device is no longer necessary to explore these paths. This also works: `pkg=org.qtproject.example.myApp && adb shell run-as $pkg ls -l /data/user/0/$pkg/files`